# How to create NxM matrix from numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

I was looking into forming around 60 rows and 11 columns matrix from NumPy array. I looked into several methods but I can't get it to work. I tried following code and got this error,

```
stats_features_full = np.empty((0, 11))
for ls in range(60):
    current_list = ls
    print('Entering list {0} for feature extraction'.format(current_list))
    stats_features = get_selected_statistics_features(list_values=list[ls])
    stats_features_np_shape = np.array(stats_features).shape
    print('Statistical Features Extracted from list: ', stats_features)
    print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from list: ', stats_features_np_shape)
    stats_features_full = np.concatenate([stats_features_full, np.array(stats_features)], axis=0)
    # stats_features_full = np.append(arr=stats_features_full, values=np.array(stats_features), axis=0)
    stats_features_full_np_shape = np.array(stats_features_full).shape
    print('Statistical Features Extracted from all lists: ', stats_features_full)
    print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from all lists: ', stats_features_full_np_shape)
```

Error Messages:

(1)

```
stats_features_full = np.concatenate([stats_features_full, np.array(stats_features)], axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

(2)

```
print('Entering list {0} for feature extraction'.format(current_list))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in append
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Is there a way to create a 60x11 array?

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to @Krish it seems to work fine. I just have another question, I want to convert the `stats_features_full` variable into a pandas dataframe in order to save the result as a text file. How can I approach this problem? See my approach below:

```
    ########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
############################################### Feature Datasets #######################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
Stats_DataFrame_Feature = stats_features_full
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list = list(Stats_DataFrame_Feature)
# print('Statistical DataFrame Featureset list: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list)
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape = np.array(Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list).shape
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape_1 = np.array(Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list).shape
print('Statistical DataFrame Featureset list shape: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape)
print('Statistical DataFrame Featureset list shape: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape_1[0])


for Stat_row in range(60):
    StatsData.append(Stats_DataFrame_Feature[0:Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape[0]])
    StatsData_np = np.array(StatsData)
    with open('filepath\dataset.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for i in range(60):
            print('Opened file number: {0}'.format(i))
            out_string = ""
            out_string += pd.DataFrame(data=StatsData_np).to_string()
            out_file.write(out_string)
            break
        # break
    # break

Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Matrix = StatsData
print('Final Saved Statistical Feature Dataset file: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Matrix)
print('Shape Final Saved Statistical Feature Dataset file: ', np.array(Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Matrix).shape)
```

My error message:

```
out_string += pd.DataFrame(data=StatsData_np).to_string()
mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
values = prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
raise ValueError("Must pass 2-d input")
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

**Edit 2:**

I managed to get it to work by changing the following lines,

```
StatsData.append(Stats_DataFrame_Feature[0:Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape[1]])
StatsData_np = np.array(StatsData[Stat_row])
```

but, I got the saved file to be following dimensions (60,11,11). Why is that?

**Edit 3:**

say that I created 6 dictionary keys and each key has 10 lists. I want to implement the same thing but I keep on getting index error.

```
for key in range(0, 6, 1):
    list_key = np.array(dict_list[key])
    print('Key value: {0}'.format(key))
    arr_list = []
    for list_num in range(0, 10, 1):
        list_val_num = np.array(list(list_key[:, list_num][0]))
        # stats_features = get_statistics_features_final(list_values=list_val_num)
        stats_features = get_selected_statistics_features(list_values=list_val_num)
        stats_features_np_shape = np.array(stats_features).shape
        print('Statistical Features Extracted from list: ', stats_features)
        print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from list: ', stats_features_np_shape)
        arr_list += [stats_features]
f_arr_list += arr_list
stats_features_full = np.vstack(f_arr_list)
stats_features_full_np_shape = np.array(stats_features_full).shape
print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from all lists: ', stats_features_full_np_shape)
```

Error Message:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: Do you understand the error?  `concatenate` is picky about the dimensions of its arguments.  You know the difference between 2 dimensions and 1, right?  That said, repeated `concatenate` in a loop is an inefficient way of building an array, and as you found hard to get right.

Comment: You defined `stats_features_full` as 2d, right?  But what is 
 `np.array(stats_features)`?  The error indicates it is 1d, but `concatenate` expects it to be 2d.  A shape of (1,11) would work nicely with the original (0,11).

Comment: `np.vstack` as recommended in the answer is like `concatenate`, except it makes sure all arguments are at least 2d, and can thus be joined as rows.  Both work with a list of arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, I changed my code to the vstack and managed to get it to work. I have another question, have a look at edit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of data I've used `np.random.rand(11)`:

```
import numpy as np
arr_list = []
for ls in range(60):
    stats_features_np_shape = np.random.rand(11)
    arr_list += [stats_features_np_shape]

stats_features_full = np.vstack(arr_list)
print(stats_features_full)
```

The key thing not here is that `stats_features_np_shape` should have a shape of `(11)` (or any integer) and `stats_features_full` is best generated outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I just have another question, I want to convert the stats_features_full variable to a pandas dataframe in order to save it as a txt file. See edit 1 in question for details.

Comment: Pandas is a little out of my comfort zone, but I highly recommend reading this guide to numpy and pandas - this is probably the single best resource I have seen to date: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/index.html

Comment: I have another question, please see the updated question (Edit 3)

Comment: You are better off creating a separate question to answer that, @WDpad159

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, thanks to @Krish and @hpaulj. Find the full code below:

```
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
############################################ Feature Extraction ########################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
arr_list = []
for ls in range(60):
    current_list = ls
    print('Entering list {0} for feature extraction'.format(current_list))
    stats_features = get_selected_statistics_features(list_values=list[ls])
    arr_list += [stats_features]
    stats_features_np_shape = np.array(stats_features).shape
    print('Statistical Features Extracted from list: ', stats_features)
    print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from list: ', stats_features_np_shape)
stats_features_full = np.vstack(arr_list)
stats_features_full_np_shape = np.array(stats_features_full).shape
print('Statistical Features Shape Extracted from all lists: ', stats_features_full_np_shape)

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
############################################### Feature Datasets #######################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
Stats_DataFrame_Feature = stats_features_full
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list = list(Stats_DataFrame_Feature)
print('Statistical DataFrame Featureset list: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list)
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape = np.array(Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list).shape
print('Statistical DataFrame Featureset list shape: ', Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape)

for Stat_row in range(60):
    StatsData.append(Stats_DataFrame_Feature[0:Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape[0]])
    Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_list = Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list[0:Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Data_list_shape[0]]
    StatsData_np = np.array(StatsData[Stat_row])
    with open('filepath\list dataset.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for i in range(60):
            print('Opened file number: {0}'.format(i))
            out_string = ""
            out_string += pd.DataFrame(data=StatsData_np).to_string()
            out_file.write(out_string)
            break
Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Matrix = StatsData
print('Shape Final Saved Statistical Feature Dataset file: ', np.array(Stats_DataFrame_Feature_Matrix).shape)
StatsData_np = np.array(StatsData)

column_no = 0
StatsData = []
stats_features_full = np.array([])
```